# Matrix and a Linear Function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions

I'm a student of electrical engineering. At our math class we were given following assignment: given a matrix 
$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ and a function $f(x) = x^5 - x^3 + 5x^2 + 8$, compute $f(A)$.

I've checked out [this PDF document](https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m14f04/public_html/math_14_matrices), but I don't think I understand it properly. I have tried by assuming that first element (let me denote it as $a_{11}$) should equal $$a_{11}=1^5-1^3+5\cdot 1+8=13$$ and second element $a_{12}$ should consequently equal $$a_{12} = 0 + 0+ 0 + 8=8$$

As it turns out (according to professor's solutions), $a_{11}$ really is $13$, but $a_{12}$ is zero. Final solution should be $$f(A) = \begin{pmatrix}
13 & 0 & 24 \\ 0 & 13 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 13
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now, I know that this site **is not** meant for students to ask questions and anticipate full solution to their problems, so instead I'm just asking for a guideline. Can somebody please give me any hint on how to solve this task?

Comment: You're taking powers element-wise, but you need to take powers matrix-wise, since the whole matrix $A$ is the argument to $f$.

Comment: Careful: multiplying a matrix $A$ with a vector can be seen as a _linear function_ (also: _linear transformation_), but the function $f$ in your question is a **non-linear** function. You are asked to find the image of $A$ under that function $f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried by assuming that first element (let me denote it as $a_{11}$) should equal $$a_{11}=1^5-1^3+5\cdot 1+8=13$$ and second element $a_{12}$ should consequently equal $$a_{12} = 0 + 0+ 0 + 8=8$$

You seem to think that you can use $f(x) = x^5 - x^3 + 5x^2 + 8$ to compute $f(A)$ by applying $f$ to each element, i.e. you assume that the element $a_{ij}$ of $A^5$ can be found by computing $f(a_{11})$ but that's not how it works. You need to *multiply matrices* to get the matrix powers.

When $A$ is diagonal, then $A^n$ is simply the result of raising the diagonal elements to the $n$th power but this does not work in general, for non-diagonal matrices. If you see a pattern in the powers of $A$, you could try proving it and using it, such as in [zoli's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2215837/159845).

---

You could simply calculate $f(A)=A^5 - A^3 + 5A^2 + 8$ by repeated multiplication; you only need to perform 3 matrix multiplications and the calculations are quite easy (thanks to the many zeroes):

- $\color{blue}{A^2} = A\cdot A = \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}=\color{blue}{\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 4 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}}$
- $\color{purple}{A^3} =  \color{blue}{A^2}\cdot A = \color{blue}{\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 4 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}}\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}=\color{purple}{\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 6 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}}$
- $\color{red}{A^5} =  \color{purple}{A^3}\cdot \color{blue}{A^2} = \color{purple}{\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 6 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}}\color{blue}{\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 4 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}}=\color{red}{\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 10 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}}$

And then:
$$\begin{align}f(A) & = \color{red}{A^5} - \color{purple}{A^3} + 5\color{blue}{A^2} + 8I_3 \\[6pt]
 & = \color{red}{\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 10 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}}-\color{purple}{\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 6 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}}+5\color{blue}{\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 4 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}}+\begin{pmatrix}
8 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 8 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 8
\end{pmatrix}  \\[10pt]
& = \begin{pmatrix}
13 & 0 & 24\\ 0 & 13 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 13
\end{pmatrix}\end{align}
$$

---

Alternatively, you can make use of [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) which states that a matrix satisfies its own characteristic polynomial; in the case of your matrix $A$ this means:
$$-A^3 + 3 A^2 - 3 A + I_3=0_3$$
From this, you have:

- $\color{blue}{A^3 = 3 A^2 - 3 A + I_3}$
- $A^4 = A^3\cdot A = \color{blue}{A^3} - 3 A^2 + A = 6A^2-8A+3I_3$
- $A^5 =  A^4\cdot A  = 6\color{blue}{A^3}-8A^2+3A = 10A^2-15A+6I_3$

And then:
$$\begin{align}f(A) & = A^5 - A^3 + 5A^2 + 8I_3 \\[6pt]
& = 10A^2-15A+6I_3 - \left( 3 A^2 - 3 A + I_3 \right)+5A^2+ 8I_3 \\[6pt]
& = 12A^2-12A+13I_3
\end{align}$$

Now you only need to perform 1 matrix multiplication to get $A^2$ (see above), then:
$$f(A) = 12\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 4 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}-12\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
13 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 13 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 13
\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}
13 & 0 & 24\\ 0 & 13 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 13
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: That was very informative! Although I didn't read your answer as first I'm voting it to be the solution. I hope somebody else can benefit from this extensive post. Thank you so much!

Comment: @PeroWhatshisnamović You're welcome, I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

I claim that

$$A^n = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}^n=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2n\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.\tag 1$$

By the principle of mathematical induction, first, for $n=2$

$$A^2 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}^2=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 4 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
then assuming that

$$A^{n-1}= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}^{n-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2(n-1) \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

we have

$$A^n=A^{n-1}A =$$
$$= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}^{n-1}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}=$$
$$=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2(n-1) \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2n\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

---

So, $(1)$ is true. Then

$$A^5 =\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 10\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},A^3 =\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 6\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}, 5A^2 =\begin{pmatrix}
5 & 0 & 20\\ 0 & 5 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 5\end{pmatrix}.  $$

Finally,

$$f(A) = A^5 - A^3 + 5A^2 + 8I=$$
$$=\begin{pmatrix}
13 & 0 & 24\\ 0 & 13 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 13\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: I think you want 13's on the diagonal (mind the minus in $\color{red}{-}A^3$)? And you have a typo at $Ax^2 (\to 5A^2)$.

Comment: Yess. Will correct. Thank you.

Comment: I read your answer as first and I did calculations myself. It turns perfectly fine. Thank you so much for your time and energy invested. It really did help!